# Identify state changes of vector

Tags: r

i have a vector with values OFF/ON from a sensor. The vector starts always with ON but can end with either ON or OFF. IF the last run in the end is ON, then the whole last ON run should be ignored.

I would like to identify the positions where the state changes. For example

```
ON, OFF, OFF, ON, ON, OFF, OFF, ON, ON, ON, ON, OFF, OFF, OFF, OFF
```

in this example it should return

```
1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v1 <- c("ON",
  "OFF",
  "OFF",
  "ON",
  "ON",
  "OFF",
  "OFF",
  "ON",
  "ON",
  "ON",
  "ON",
  "OFF",
  "OFF",
  "OFF",
  "OFF",
  "ON")

 # which values differ from their 1 lagged values
(indexes <- which(v1!=c(NA,head(v1,-1))))

if(tail(v1[indexes],1)=="ON"){
  print("Discard the last")
  indexes <- head(indexes,-1)
}

indexes
v1[indexes]
```